Issue with Crawling Updated Table Data in a SPA with JavaScript
I'm developing a crawler for a service that is built as a Single Page Application (SPA).
I am unsure whether the framework used is React, Angular, or something else. My crawler interacts with a table that is displayed after clicking a button with the ID queries-process-button. The table has a class i3WFpf.
When I first crawl the table, everything works perfectly, and the data is correctly retrieved. However, when I navigate to another menu and try to crawl the new table data, my crawler still returns the data from the initial table, even though the table content has visually updated on the page.
Interestingly, when I reload the entire page and then crawl the new table, the correct data is retrieved. But again, the problem persists when I attempt to crawl any subsequent table.
Here’s a snippet of the code I'm using in the browser's console:
const table = document.querySelector('table.i3WFpf');

if (table) {
    const rows = table.rows;

    for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        let cells = rows[i].cells;
        let rowData = [];
        for (let j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
            rowData.push(cells[j].innerText); 
        }
        console.log(`Row ${i + 1}:`, rowData);
    }
} else {
    console.log("Table with class 'i3WFpf' not found.");
}

Now how can I modify my crawler to correctly retrieve the updated table data without needing to reload the page?
Is there a way to ensure that the crawler always fetches the latest data displayed in the table, particularly in the context of SPAs?

Based on the information available so far, I can only guess here - but it sounds like that site you are scraping might simply create a new second table, and hide the first one. But document.querySelector('table.i3WFpf') will of course only ever get you the first matching element found in the document.

@C3roe It's possible, but I doubt it. This service is related to one of Google's services called Search Console.

You are doing your scraping on the client side there, so this can only capture what is currently in the DOM. If you are still getting the "old data", when "new data" is already being shown - then that can only mean, that "old data" is still in the DOM.

@C3roe Right, I also think that the DOM hasn't been updated. Now, knowing this, what do you think can be done to solve this problem?

Have you used your browser dev tools to inspect the shown elements?

@C3roe yes I used dev tools to inspect new data's and execute above code

And the element containing the new content, actually matches the selector table.i3WFpf? But then querySelector would still only get you the first element that matches the selector, if the old one still exists in the DOM. You might need to use querySelectorAll, then pick the last table, or something like that.

@C3roe Well done, my friend!
Add your Answer please for choosing that

const table = document.querySelector('table.i3WFpf');

querySelector will only return the first element that matches the selector.
If the site you want to scrape loads additional data into a table that matches that same selector, and only hides the original table, but keeps it in the DOM - then you need to switch to using querySelectorAll, and then pick the last (presumably?) matching element it finds.
